# Cython __pyx_r may be used uninitialized in this function

Tags: python, c++, cython

I am trying to utilize cython to provide a wrapper for my C++ utilities. One such function I am trying to make accessible is an accessor that returns an enum based on file type.

Here is how I re-define the function in cython:

```
cdef extern from "reader.h" namespace "magic_number":
   enum mcr_magic_number_t:                                                                              
      MDI = 0                                                                                            
      EOT                                                                                                
      RV                                                                                                 
      UNKNOWN
```

and then in my `reader.pxd` file I have

```
cpdef mcr_magic_number_t magic_number(self)
```

and then in my `reader.pyx` file I have

```
cpdef mcr_magic_number_t magic_number(self):            
   """                                           
   :return: the magic_number enum                       
   :rtype: mcr_magic_number_t                           
   """                                                  
   return self.thisptr.magic_number()
```

Now, when I go to compile this, I get a warning

`warning: ‘__pyx_r’ may be used uninitialized in this function`

Anyone know how is best to get around this? I tried searching for solutions on google but all I got were pages of other people reporting the same __pyx_r warning. Maybe there is a way to set a default value or to make sure that it is always initialized within cython?

Comment: I suspect it's a non-issue. However, if in doubt have a look at the C to see what circumstances it isn't initialized in. Unfortunately, without knowing what `self.thisptr` is, it isn't really possible for anyone else to have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking self.thisptr for non-NULL value:

```
if <void*>self.thisptr != NULL:
    return self.thisptr.magic_number()
```